# How to install vim8 without effecting the built-in vim?

Tags: vi

How can install vim8 without effecting the built-in vim that comes with a mac? Like with python2 that comes built-in with a mac, I have python3 separate. So, I can call it with vim8. I am using brew.

My OSX is 10.11.6.

Comment: Maybe you can change the name of the binary file or put it in /usr/local/bin and whenever you need to run that command you will have to run `/usr/local/bin/vim8`

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew will not overwrite any Apple supplied executables. It installs everything in /usr/local which is empty by default.

I think Homebrew will install vin to /usr/local/vim

However if you installed python3 from python.org then that will conflict with Homebrew python as they are both installed in /usr/local

Comment: I was not aware that Homebrew will not overwrite any Apple supplied executables.

I installed vim via brew, but mine is installed in /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.1250/bin/vim and I had to create an alias to vim8. I will have update my alias each time I update vim. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I think brew has a way of doing that . But I don't use brew **because** it uses /usr/local and depends on random bits of Apple structure that can get updated.

Comment: what do you use instead?

Comment: macports - fink also is outside /usr/local